# Align div tags, Need to put Horizontal tabs after the form

Tags: html, css

1. How to add the horizontal tabs at the end of the form.
2. Need only one scrollbar to scroll the complete page, currently I have got two due to two vertical divs.

Please help.

https://jsfiddle.net/756douvt/

```
<div>
    <div class="split left">
        <div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="split right">
        <div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div>
        <div class="w3-bar w3-black">
            <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button tablink w3-red" onclick="openCity(event,'London')">London</button>
            <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button tablink" onclick="openCity(event,'Paris')">Paris</button>
            <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button tablink" onclick="openCity(event,'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
        </div>

        <div id="London" class="w3-container w3-border city">
            <h2>London</h2>
            <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="Paris" class="w3-container w3-border city" style="display:none">
            <h2>Paris</h2>
            <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="Tokyo" class="w3-container w3-border city" style="display:none">
            <h2>Tokyo</h2>
            <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

---

Try this it should help

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/upa6q8k3/)

```
select {
        width: 160%;
        padding: 2px;
    }
```

---

Try not to exceed the width more than 100%

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering your first question because the second is not clear enough:
I added an inline style to the "w3-bar" declaring the div with a fixed position and setting it be fixed at the bottom.

If I can get a clearer picture of what you are trying to implement, I can rewrite the code and share the fiddle link with you.

```
<div class="w3-bar w3-black" style="position: fixed; bottom: 0">
                <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button tablink w3-red" onclick="openCity(event,'London')">London</button>
                <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button tablink" onclick="openCity(event,'Paris')">Paris</button>
                <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button tablink" onclick="openCity(event,'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
            </div>
```